# Почему request запускается в конце работы цикла, а не на каждом его шагу?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

Допустим есть такая программа:

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  request("ссылка", function(err, resp, html) {
    if (!err){
       const $ = cheerio.load(html);
       console.log("!!");
    };
  });
};
```

**На выходе** я получу: 0, 1, 2, !!, !!, !!.

**Почему** я **не получаю**: 0, !!, 1, !!, 2, !! ???

Comment: Потому что `request` - асинхронная функция.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый лучший вариант, организовывать цикл через if

```
var a = 0
var l = 'https://www.google.com/'
function test2() {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(l, function(err, resp, html) {
      if (!err){
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        console.log(' hello ');
        resolve();
      }
    })
  });
  promise.then(
    result => {
      if (a<10) {
        console.log(a);
        a++
        test2()
      }
    },
    reject => {
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function executeRequest(i) {
  console.log(i);
  request("ссылка", function(err, resp, html) {
    if (!err) {
       const $ = cheerio.load(html);
       console.log("!!");
    }

    if (--i > 0) {
      executeRequest(i);
    }
  });
}

executeRequest(3);
```

Comment: Это какая то магия, но работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Это не магия, это просто хороший код. (С) P.S магии в программировании нет, к сожалению или к счастью.

Comment: вместо 0 наверное лучше -1

Comment: @RomaRomin я показал принцип, подкрутить и настроить - полностью в Вашей власти :)

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно дело в том, что ваш цикл, не ждёт когда прийдет ответ по вашему запросу и начинает каждый раз следующую итерацию, а ответы приходят позже, и выводятся по очереди. Вы можете исправить это, используя ["промисы"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Пример

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          request("ссылка", function(err, resp, html) {
              if (!err){
                  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
                  resolve();
              }
         })
    });

    promise.then(
        result => {
            console.log(i);
            console.log("!!");
        }, 
        reject => {
        }
     );
}
```

Comment: А можете показать пример в данной элементарной программе как использовать "промисы"?

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавив работу с "промисами". Код может иметь некоторые ошибки, так как я писал с мобильного телефона, если что, уточните.

Comment: Хочу проголосовать за ответ, но не могу пока в тексте присутствует совет про `setTimeout` :).

Comment: Примного благодарен, удалю момент про `SetTimeout`, учту что это «очень не хорошо»! :)

Comment: Почему SetTimeout это «очень не хорошо» ???

Comment: Ну потому что сама по себе пауза через функцию которая назначена на отложенный вызов, это не очень даже по техническим соображениям.

Comment: Потому что, используя `setTimeout`, Вы как бы говорите: "я точно знаю, что ответ на запрос придет не более, чем через столько-то миллисекунд". Вы это знаете?

Comment: неа, не знаю. Могу лишь догадываться

Comment: @RomaRomin это был риторический вопрос

Comment: @Igor как же это все-таки забавно когда Ваши реторические вопросы не понимают, просто не передать. Поднимает настроение. :)))

Comment: я на самом деле понимал, но хотелось вставить Ремарку, а также продолжить разговор и еще раз поблагодарить всех за оказанную помощь

Comment: Ремарк встает и говорит, а мне за что вставлять?

Comment: Ахахах. :) Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: Код не работает, как ожидается в вопросе. Результат будет:  hello 
3
!!
 hello 
3
!!
 hello 
3
!!. Только через if циклы.